# freeTDS not working via macOS Terminal

Tags: sql, sql-server, macos, freetds

I'm using this guide to use my Mac to connect to a MS-SQL-Server:
https://github.com/lionheart/django-pyodbc/wiki/Mac-setup-to-connect-to-a-MS-SQL-Server

On step three, I'm trying to run freeTDS and check whether it works, but I'm getting this error:

locale is "en_US.UTF-8"
locale charset is "UTF-8"
using default charset "UTF-8"
Error 20009 (severity 9):
    Unable to connect: Adaptive Server is unavailable or does not exist
There was a problem connecting to the server.

I'm also trying to run the MSSQL server outside of the docker container
(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/quickstart-install-connect-docker)
I'm not sure if I'm missing a step here, I'm able to enter the prompt asked and it doesn't complain, but it doesn't produce anything either.

Comment: This won't solve your FreeTDS issue, but you may want to consider using `django-pyodbc-azure` - it works for both SQL Server and Azure and is the best maintained Django engine for SQL Server I've seen. https://github.com/michiya/django-pyodbc-azure

Comment: On to your problem: can you amend your question to include what command you are using to test `FreeTDS`? Thanks!